# python 2.7.9 please help me with IndentationError (print)

Tags: python, printing

I'm using python 2.7.9 and mac terminal, and I have a problem with `IndentationError` for print:

```
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a,b=0,1
>>> while b<10:
... print b
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print b
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>
```

I think it's not a problem with print function
for example, I can get a result like this..

```
>>> print b
1
```

Comment: Python is a language that relies on indentation. You want to read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) again to refresh how that works. You didn't indent the `print` line in the `while` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` block must be indented:

```
while b<10:
    print b
```

As Martijn said, indentation and white space is important in Python and changes the meaning of the code (unlike many other languages).

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing this in the interpreter:

> > > > a,b=0,1 
> > > >         while b<10: 
> > > >            ... print b

you could be forgiven for thinking the interpreter treats your next line as indented, but it doesn't. You simply have to add a tab before typing "print b", and then enter key twice to finish the loop.

Note that when this works, you'll get an infinite loop of '1' printing every line in your terminal, which you'll have to end by killing it. You kill it with 'CTRL+C' or its equivalent in OSX.